# Determine console.group() depth

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am using `console.group()` for extensive debugging in my code, and at some points would like to close all groups to be at the root level. I don't know of any method in the API to close all the groups at once, so my best bet so far has been just writing `console.groupEnd()` multiple times. However, I would like to place this in a for loop that just closes all of them, so I don't need to worry about updating it in the future.

I know I can of course keep my own counter open, but I'm hoping to not have to do that.

If possible, how might I go about doing this, or something like it?

Comment: I just took a look through the documentation. It looks like you'll have to resort to using a counter.

Comment: I second that, you will likely need a counter.

Comment: yes a counter seems the only way really. You could at least internalise it a bit by overriding `console.group()` and incrementing the counter in there before calling the built-in `console.group`

Comment: How does it internally keep track of things? For example, if I try to `console.groupEnd()` and there are no groups to end, how does it handle that? (What I'm getting at: does it keep an Array or some structure of open group objects?)